# Is this denominator of a posterior distribution the marginal distribution of Y?

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability#Calculation):

[image], where [image]

---

Is the denominator (above pics are from Wiki) the marginal distribution of Y?

Intuitively, it seems that way so that when we cross-multiply, LHS and RHS are mirrors.

Proof:

Denom = $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(x)f_{Y | X=x}(y) dx$

$= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{XY}(x,y) dx$ (um, right?)

$= f_Y(y)$

Is that right?

Comment: The difficulty here with a yes-or-no question like this is if the answer is "yes", we can't actually post an answer to the question, since single sentence answers (let alone single word ones) aren't really allowed. Yes, it's right, but how in general does one expand on that?

Comment: @Glen_b What about those proof verification questions on Math SE? :|

Comment: I don't want to comment on other SE sites. I'd just like to encourage attempting to phrase questions here in a way that invites a slightly more substantive answer than "yes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see one other thing to comment on here, so I will answer.

1. Yes, that's correct.
2. It would be unusual to use $x$ for a parameter, and if it weren't a parameter, even more unusual to call $f_{Y|X=x}$ a likelihood; That usage there in the Wikipedia article is in total contradiction to the earlier use in the same article (where it was a random variable), and also breaks the typical convention of using Greek letters for parameters. Conventions can be broken when there's a reason to; I see no reason for it to have been done there.

Comment: Oh, I'll be sure to use greeks for parameters. Thanks Glen_b ^-^

Comment: There are times when it makes sense not to. People tend to balk these days at using $\pi$ for population proportions in elementary texts (though when I learned stats it was still very common); I don't cavil about that, for example. Also, in some works there aren't really enough suitable Greek letters to do everything, and then you don't have much choice. I've done things (moderately complicated situations for MCMC) with many dozens of different symbols needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Bayes Theorem is just a restatement of the basic definiton of conditional probability:

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(B)}$$

And in the denominator:

$$P(B)=\sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}}P(A_i)P(B|A_i)$$

Where the $\{A_i\}$ are a mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive partition of the sample space.

You should be able to think of your formula for the posterior in the continuous mixture case in these terms if it helps.

Comment: Oh right. I forgot to point out that the denominator ought to have resembled the denominator in Bayes' Theorem. Thanks Mike ^-^